# Writing utf-8 to Excel CSV

Tags: python, csv, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

When opening a `.csv` file in Excel that has been created by the `csv` module in python using `utf-8` encoding, the characters are corrupted.

How can I prevent this error from occuring in my Excel `.csv` files?

#### Example

When writing `u'\xe9'` (i.e. `'é'`), in `'utf-8'`, Excel displays `'ã©'` as if it has done some kind of decoding from `'latin-1'` encoding:

```
print u'\xe9' # basic unicode string
é
u'\xe9'.encode('utf-8') #encode to write into .csv as utf-8
'\xc3\xa9'
u'\xe9'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1') # Example of incorrect decoding to unicode
u'\xc3\xa9'
print u'\xe9'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1') # print statement == Excel's faulty encoding
ã©
```

Comment: python 2 or python 3 ? (also, which operating system?)

Comment: This seemed to fix my issue for now: When writing to the csv file object, I found that by writing the following before anything else seemed to force the correct behaviour`f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf-8'))` - where `f` is the file object specified by `with open(filename, 'wb') as f:`

Comment: Windows 7, Python 2.7.x

Comment: In the absence of any contrary indication, Excel will open the file in the prevailing code page. By putting a BOM ('\ufeff') at the front of the file you're specifically telling it the file is UTF-8. P.S. You can self-answer if you have a solution.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll put the answer in now - I don't like to self-answer because often people see it's been self-answered and don't put a better solution! Aside, @MarkRansom, what is the *prevailing code page* for Excel (or in this instance) ?

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane You can do that automatically by using `'utf-8-sig'` as encoding.

Answer (score 4):

When writing to the csv file object, I found that by writing the following before anything else forced the correct behaviour:

```
f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf-8'))
```

where `f` is the file object specified by `with open(filename, 'wb') as f:`

As per [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508393/writing-utf-8-to-excel-csv?noredirect=1#comment50979438_31508393)'s comment above: the BOM specifically tells Excel to use `utf-8` encoding

Answer (score 1):

Python has a codec that will add a BOM character.  Excel requires this BOM character to detect UTF-8.  The codec will also remove the BOM for you when decoding:

```
>>> u'\xe9'.encode('utf-8-sig')
'\xef\xbb\xbf\xc3\xa9'
>>> u'\xe9'.encode('utf-8-sig').decode('utf-8')
u'\ufeff\xe9'
>>> u'\xe9'.encode('utf-8-sig').decode('utf-8-sig')
u'\xe9'
```